# Lock excel work book using apache poi api java

Tags: java, excel, file, locking, apache-poi

I have to lock a workbook while reading and writing a row.

Is there way to accomplish this using `Apache` POI API without protecting and password option?.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, paste some of your code that could help others to understand and solve the problem.

As far as I know you can't "lock" the hole `Workbook` but one thing you can try is to apply a `CellStyle` to cells you want to protect while reading or writing.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

CellStyle lockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
lockedCellStyle.setLocked(true);

Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
// .... Create rows and cells as needed

// When Writing or reading
Cell cell = getCellsToLockWithAnyMethod();
cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);
```